# How do I store values for each candle

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am looking for some guidance on trying trying to store values for each candle, for the last 50 candles.
The values I'm trying to store are open price (to remember)and volume (to sum up accumulative volume throughout that period).

Once another candle crosses a stored open price within the 50 candle range, the volume for that original candle value is then minus off the volume accumulation. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store the last 50 open price individually, you can use the [arrays](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html).

However, that might not be necessary.

You can use the built-in `math.sum()` function which returns the sliding sum of last y values of x.

> math.sum(source, length) → series float

Or, you can use the `ta.cum()` built-in function, which is sum of all elements of `source`.

> ta.cum(source) → series float

If you want to calculate the average of something, you can use the `ta.sma` built-in function which is the sum of last y values of x, divided by y.

> ta.sma(source, length) → series float

Also, you can take advantage of the `var` keyword to create a variable that will keep its value on each new execution. Remember that your script will be executed on each bar, so you can update this variable only when you want, otherwise it will keep its value.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response Vitruvius its really appreciated. I do need the values individually rather than an average of them as I need to know which volume figure I need to minus off depending on whether a subsequent candle has passed the stored open price of one of the previous candles within the array. I hope this makes sense, so I think an array would work best however I cant seem to figure this out or how code the full scope of the candle to check against previous candles